# Shouldn't this question be closed as "too broad", since it actually asks about two distinct items?

Tags: discussion

There is a question about the recent series of *Black Mirror*, inquiring to [the meaning behind the titles of two episodes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84383/why-are-the-episodes-crocodile-and-hang-the-dj-named-that-way).

Shouldn't this be closed as "too broad", and the poster be required to split them up into two separate questions, considering it is entirely possible that only one of those is answerable? Since it is impossible to select two answers as the correct one...

Comment: There seems to be only a single answer about the 2nd title anyway (and none about both).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson my answer address both ;)

Answer (score -1):

No, the question asks for the reasoning for the names, which is applicable to more than one title at a time. In this case the two titles are an exception and an answer to both would present a common theme or address a lack of one.

Comment: I don't see how the question or its answers suggest a *common* inherent theme of naming between the two, though. Those were just the two that the asker couldn't figure out himself, which might be entirely different ones for you or me. In fact there's answers only tackling *either* of the titles and they don't seem related in any way. (Unless I'm missing some connection that an inclined *Black Mirror* enthusiast might want to add to the question.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson You overlook the obvious: the show's creators and whatever criteria they might have for what makes an adequate episode title. In this case two were _not obvious_ and a single answer can address both instances, i.e. no need to close as "too broad"

Comment: It might be my lack of *Black Mirror* experience to acknowledge how the other episode titles were completely obvious and thus entirely different from those two. To me as an outsider it looks like he could as well just have picked 2 other episodes he didn't get the titles, or 3 or 5, depending only on what he thinks is obvious. I'm sure the other obvious episodes had a good reason for their title, too.

Comment: I know a single answer could theoretically adress both titles. The fact that from the existing 5 answers none does so yet, though, is at least pointing to a problem.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson "too broad" is not the problem.

Comment: But that's the standard close-reason when we're asking multiple unrelated questions whose answers would just create a mess of partial answers. Granted, it's two episodes from the very same series, but the question fails to establish a connection between the two beyond that.

Comment: But well, I haven't voted on anything...yet. Neither has *anyone* else. So I acknowledge this isn't a super clear situation (though, much of the conflict comes from answers already *existing*). Therefore the question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson So address the actual problem - _the partial answers._ If need be, edit the question to give it laser like focus. Just closing it as "too broad" won't address the former.

Comment: It might, though. Since the answers are actually okay. You could pracitcally leave 5 of the 6 where they are by just editing the "Hang the DJ" thing out and encouraging the asker to put it into a new question (to which the answer can be transferred too). It *does* require manually reposting the question and 1 of the 6 answers, but it's not like we necessarily need to trash the *entire* question either. As said, what *isn't* yet clear to me is if the question actually *asks* for wholesome answers to begin with, if it isn't really, then the partial answers aren't necessarily the answers' fault.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson considering the votes the question has received, as is it's useful to the community (and more so than any of the answers). As per BCdotWeb's question, I don't think it warrants closure for being too broad nor "requiring" the question be split into two. If anything, re-wording the question to explain any and all of the titles' meanings might be more useful.

Comment: While these episodes are linked through various details, they are stand-alone. I fail to see how adding the titles and their (possible) explanation for other episodes in this season improves the question, since the problem is that possibly two *separate* answers could provide an explanation for each, and that would cause an issue because one of them would not be picked as the canonical answer by the poster.